# Spring data rest merge patch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I am using **spring data rest** in my project and have question about 
`application/merge-patch+json` request.
While `application/json-patch+json` request works good i have troubles with merge-patch.
For example i have nested object without repository like this

```
"student":{
  "id":1,
  "address":{
   "id":1,
   "street":2,
   "building":2
 }
}
```

And i am sending `PATCH`, `application/merge-patch+json` to `students/1`
with this payload

```
{
  "address":{
   "street":3
  }
}
```

I am getting this result

```
"student":{
  "id":1,
  "address":{
   "id":2,
   "street":3,
   "building":null
 }
}
```

So spring data rest just created new address object instead of merging.

Java code is like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long studentId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressId")
    private Address address;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Address class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private long addressId;
     private String street;
     private String building;

     //getters and setters
}
```

Also student have rest repository and address have not

My question is how i can achieve correct behavior in merging patch requests in spring data rest?

Comment: Same problem for me with a @ElementCollection Map<Basic,Embeddable>. PATCHING a property of a nested Embeddable erased the entire Map and added a new Embeddable. This is dangerous behavior

Answer (score 0):

Though it is delayed response, it can be helpful to others who has same issue

In the input JSON, address **id** is missing.

```
{
  "address":{
   "id" : 1,  
   "street":3
  }
}
```